# How to fetch multiple phone numbers from MySQL table and store them in a variable by comma separated in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm new to PHP-MySQL array functions. So I need help for the following:

I need to select phone numbers of all users from the MySQL table "users" in PHP and then need to store the phone numbers in a variable. All the numbers should be separated by "," (comma).

What I have tried:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT phone FROM users WHERE status = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$status);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($phone);
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $allphones = "$phone,"; //need help here.
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

What I need:

```
$allphones = "9999999990,9999999991,9999999992,9999999993";
```

all the phone numbers should be separated by comma (,) and stored in a variable like above.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: **$allphones . = "$phone,";** after loop $allphones=rtrim($allphones,',');

Comment: If you are wondering that @404BrainNotFound just did then here is the explanation. When you are concatenating each phone to the `$allphones` variable, there will be an extra comma at the end of the string. With `rtrim` (right trim) function, we will remove the last comma from the right side after the loop finishes.

Comment: *"All the numbers should be separated by "," (comma)."* - That doesn't sound like a good idea. Are you wanting to "store" those as such in the database, or are they already stored as such in the database? The question is unclear (to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way. You could also fetch all to avoid declaration and initialization of a new array (allphonesArray). It's up to you.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT phone FROM users WHERE status = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$status);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($phone);

$allphonesArray = array(); //New array
while ($stmt->fetch())
{
    $allphonesArray[] = $phone; //Add each phone value to the array
}
$stmt->close(); 

$allphonesString = implode(',', $allphonesArray); //Concatenate every element and separate them with ','
echo $allphonesString;
```